# Is there any way to convert the javascript code converted from babel back to it's original es6 form?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I am working on a project that needs a lot of fixes.The core js file is converted into huge code and I guess it's done with babel .I need to to access the es6 code converted by babel.Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Babel does a one-way transformation. There's no way to get the source from the transpiled result unless you have a map file along with the bundle.

Comment: https://github.com/lebab/lebab